# Lerna is inconsistent when watching detection of changes

Tags: npm, web, build, lerna, npm-workspaces

I am trying to make a monorepo with lerna, but when i try to watch the workspace with `lerna watch` it show inconsistent results

## My project and workflow

The following image shows my workflow with :

- **top window** : lerna output of : `npx -c 'lerna watch -- echo \$LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME \$LERNA_FILE_CHANGES'` which echoes whenever it detect changes in the project ([command taken from here](https://lerna.js.org/docs/features/workspace-watching))
- **bottom left** : me with ranger (file explorer) and vim (code editor) editing random files until it works
- **bottom right** : output of nx logs : `tail blurred_path/lernatest/node_modules/.cache/nx/d/daemon.log --follow`

[image: my workflow on a simple test project]

My test project looks like this (`tree --gitignore`)

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── packages
    ├── pkgA
    │   ├── main.js
    │   └── package.json
    ├── pkgB
    │   ├── main.js
    │   └── package.json
    └── pkgC
        ├── main.js
        └── package.json
```

## Problem

When I edit files (any `./packages/pkg*/main.js` or `./packages/pkg*/package.json`), new lines are printed in nx logs (bottom right window),
And most of the time no new lines on `lerna watch` output (top window)

But sometime it does! Idk, I found no pattern ... Only when i run `npx nx reset`, the first edit always output a new line on `lerna watch`

I only once had a perfect run where each file write resulted in a new line, but when i stopped the process (^C) and retried, it restarted to be inconsistent

## My system

Output of `npx lerna info` :

```
 Environment info:

  System:
    OS: Linux 6.5 Arch Linux
    CPU: (8) x64 AMD Ryzen 3 5300U with Radeon Graphics
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.9.0 - /sbin/node
    npm: 10.2.2 - /sbin/npm
  Utilities:
    Git: 2.42.0 - /sbin/git
  npmPackages:
    lerna: ^7.4.2 => 7.4.2
```

## Some of my files

```json
# ./package.json
{
  "name": "lernatest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^7.4.2"
  }
}
```

```json
# ./lerna.json
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

```json
# ./packages/pkgA/package.json
{
  "name": "pkga",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

## Note

Btw, yes I use Arch, and ranger, and vim..

For arch i actually cannot know if it's the problem, i don't have any other computer to test on, but it's not vim, I tested on sublime text, and It shows the same inconsistencies

Comment: Same issue here, also on Arch linux. Everything seems to work fine on Mac OS though.

Comment: I opened an issue here : https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/3953